# Process.WaitForExit() not waiting for multiple Chrome instances

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process

I'm trying to start Chrome from WPF application using .NET framework 4.0 with code similar to the following:

```
var arg = string.Format("--app=\"{0}\" --window-size=1024,1000", "http://bing.com");
this._process = Process.Start("chrome.exe", arg);
this._process.WaitForExit();
// Perform relevant operations once the process completes/ exit
```

I'm opening chrome in app mode.

**Case 1:** When I have a no additional Chrome instance/window opened, WaitForExit blocks the control till the Chrome window created through code is closed - This is what I'm looking for.

**Case 2:** If I have a Chrome instance running already. Then it does not wait for the chrome instance created through code to exit and moves on to the next line. I want to have similar experience as in case 1, that is the control should be blocked until the user closes the chrome instance.

Is there anything extra I need to do get this working when I have multiple instances of Chrome already opened?

Comment: Side note: "does not work" and "does not do what I want" are somwehat different things... The fact that "chrome.exe" immediately exist in this case does not make `WaitForExit` broken, it just does not meet your goals...

Comment: When you start chrome, it looks for an existing chrome process. If it finds one, it tells that process to open a new tab/window and then exits. What do you want to wait for? The chrome tab/window that you opened to be closed?

Comment: Hi Alexei, Blorgbeard I have added edited the question and provided additional information. Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: "it does not wait for the chrome instance created through code to exit" - it does wait, it's just that the instance you create (the actual process) exits immediately, after telling the existing instance to open the window instead.  Chrome has a *lot* of command-line switches; you may be able to find something that will make it act how you want.. Have a look [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Hi @Blorgbeard you are right. 'Process.Start' does create a new instance and exit immediately. Infact, it may create more than one process. Now my problem is to identify the process (or instance) which was created by 'Process.Start'.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, I think that's a bug,

Comment: The only workaround I have found is to execute the process with a different user

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process.GetProcessesByName to get all opened chrome process,and invoke WaitForExit for each process

Comment: Hi Phenix, It does work if I put WaitForExit on all the open chrome processes but I need to wait only for the process created through code. Hence, does not really resolve my issue.

Comment: “Case 2: If I have a Chrome instance running already”. Is this chrome process created through your code?If yes ,you can use the returned Process object ,if not or other process created chrome process,i think you should record the process information,like process id,and you can get the process and wait it in your  process

Comment: Hi @Pehnix_yu, The other chrome instances are not created by code. I already have the process object (this._process) which I want to wait for. The problem is when we have multiple instances running (irrespective of whether they have been created by code or not ) then this._process.WaitForExit() does not wait for the chromes process created by code to close.

Answer (score -2):

```
Process.Start(@"%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", 
              "http:\\www.YourUrl.com");
```

You can also try with dis

```
 Process.Start("chrome", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");
```

Comment: what does this have to do with waiting for the browser to exit?

Comment: This is unrelated to what OP is asking about.